# Can an iPhone or iPod Touch communicate with another device in the same room?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, social-networking, ipod-touch

I'm new to developing applications for the iPhone and iPod touch.  Is it possible to communicate directly between 2 devices in the same room by using WiFi or perhaps even BlueTooth on the iPhone?

I've seen a demo of a fire application where one iPhone "lights" other iPhone when they get close to each other.  How is this accomplished?

The point of all this is that I am exploring the option of developing a game that you can play with another person in the same room.

Comment: I get the impression in the second paragraph, you are talking about proximity - i.e. closeness of the two devices in the same room.

If this is the case then you need to think about using shortrange technology like bluetooth, or ultrasound/audio to either kickstart the communication. Please clarify?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The iPhone supports Bonjour based service discovery and several applications take advantage of this to do things like syncing with a PC on the same network. Explore the samples and guides in the iPhone SDK. WiTap and BonjourWeb are good examples to start with. NSNetServices and CFNetServices are the APIs you'll be dealing with for Bonjour

Answer (score 6):

iPhone - iPhone communication can also be accomplished over bluetooth using [GameKit](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH100-SW1).

Comment: Didn't realize this question was over a year old. No wonder I was the first to suggest GameKit.